# How app_scoped_ids will be used on custom audience after May 1st?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

On custom audience, there is the possibility to upload a Facebook ID list for creating an audience... After the Graph API v2.0 migration, when we won't have access to Facebook ID anymore, how can i upload the user id list? Can i use a app_scoped_id based list?

If someone publishes something on my fanpage, and i get his post using Graph API, will i be able to use his id on custom audience? The official documentation don't make itself clear when explaining about the "expiring process" of a app_scoped_id. As far as i understood, when someone authorizes an application, his app_scoped_id will be "permanent", but if there is no user interaction/authorization with my application, the app_scoped_id CAN expire in 24 hours... is that right? If so, how can i use a list of ids on custom audience if they expires?

Thank you!

UPDATE

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids:

> For users who have not logged into your app, the user ID may change depending on the version of the API that you call. **In v1.0 of the API users who have not logged into your app will be referred to by their original Facebook user ID, whereas in v2.0 they will be referred to by an app-scoped ID.**
>
> We've added new API endpoints that allow you to tag and invite friends who don't use your app. These APIs return tokens which may be used to generate custom interfaces for tagging and invitations. Those tokens aren't meant to be cachable and we make no guarantees that they will be stable beyond 24 hours from the time the API response containing them was received. They aren't the same as either the IDs used on data for people not logged into your app nor the same as the app-scoped IDs.

Comment: the user HAS to authorize your app in order to get an app scoped id

Comment: Not necessarily... if you get all likes from a post for example using any valid token on Api v2.1, you will get app_scoped_ids from that, even without user authorization.

Comment: No you only get an app scoped user id when the user logs in the first time

Comment: If you do a call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/[ANY_POST_ID]/likes?access_token=[ANY_VALID_TOKEN]` you will get a list of ids and names... what is this ID? And if you take any of these and do a call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/[ANY_ID]` you will get basic public user information.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the app-scoped IDs with temporarily generated IDs.  App-scoped IDs will not change over time.  Temporarily generated IDs are meant to help with inviting and tagging friends who have not authorized an application and as such they will not remain the same over time.

Comment: I'm not getting the likes field from a post, i'm getting the likes "edge" (/likes, not &fields=likes), thats why i'm getting the list of ids and names and not just the total count of likes. And i think my confusion about the app-scoped id is because when i make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/[ANY_ID_GOT_FROM_LIKES_EDGE]` i get the basic user info, and one of these fields is the link to its facebook profile like this: `"link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/[THE_ID]/"`.

Comment: According to the documentation for the v2.1 API, there is no 'likes' edge.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page

Perhaps what you are doing was available previously and still functions as a part of the v2.x API, but it may not function the same forever.

Comment: I'm not getting likes from a page, i'm getting from a post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/post.

Comment: I see now, I misread the post.  Regardless, I mentioned app-scoped IDs do not expire and you should see no changes in this list from your likes.  After re-reading my answer, its not very clear that's what I was trying to get at.  I will edit the post.